# Output 3 Biggest Directories and 3 Biggest subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, unix

im new to unix and i want to learn unix.
someone gave this script to me.

```
#!/bin/bash

top3()
{
    awk '{
        pos=index( $0, "/" ) ;
        if( pos >0 ){
            print substr($0, pos) ;
        } ;
    }'
}

TMP=`basename "$0" ".sh" `

du -sh /var/* 2>>/dev/null | sort -hr >${TMP}.dirs
cat ${TMP}.dirs

head -3 ${TMP}.dirs | top3 >${TMP}.dirs3

rm -f ${TMP}.subdirs3
for dir in $( cat ${TMP}.dirs3 )
do
    echo -e "Doing '${dir}' ..."
    grep "${dir}"'$' ${TMP}.dirs >>${TMP}.subdirs3

    du -sh ${dir}/* 2>>/dev/null | sort -hr >${TMP}.subdirs
    head -3 ${TMP}.subdirs | awk '{ printf("\t%s\n", $0) }' >>${TMP}.subdirs3

    echo "" >>${TMP}.subdirs3
done
echo ""
cat ${TMP}.subdirs3
```

basically I want to output 3 biggest directory and its 3 biggest subdirectories and im having a hard time to understand the script. can someone help to simplify this? thanks in advance

I tried changing the path from var to log and it says

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioUUm.png)

im hoping for a simplier script.

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

#### Here a simpler and hopefully more readable solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
{
    du -sh /var/log/*/ |
        sort -rh |
        tee /dev/stderr |
        while read du path; do
            printf -- '\n%s\n' "Processing $du $path"
            du -sh "$path"* | sort -rh | head -3
            ((++c==3)) && break
        done
} 2>&1
```

##### Sample output

```
1,4G    /var/log/journal/
1,2M    /var/log/installer/
456K    /var/log/apt/
144K    /var/log/lightdm/
60K     /var/log/cups/
4,0K    /var/log/ntpstats/

Processing 1,4G /var/log/journal/
1,4G    /var/log/journal/2a7428458da7474c81169e4d51424f0c

Processing 1,2M /var/log/installer/
496K    /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz
384K    /var/log/installer/syslog
300K    /var/log/installer/partman

Processing 456K /var/log/apt/
148K    /var/log/apt/term.log
104K    /var/log/apt/eipp.log.xz
92K     /var/log/apt/term.log.3.gz
```

##### Performances

```
# time bash old.sh
real    0m3,063s
user    0m0,548s
sys     0m2,474s
```

VS

```
# time bash new.sh
real    0m0,012s
user    0m0,018s
sys     0m0,005s
```

Comment: Does it fit your needs?